# Managing PayPal Donations, Add to Cart and Subscription using single request

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, payment-gateway, paypal-sandbox

I am using website payments standard and I have the following requirement. Please let me know if a solution is available for website payments standard.

I already have subscriptions integrated to my website. I would like to have a feature that enables the user to donate a dynamic amount along with the subscription. For that, I plan to add an additional text field for the amount in my payment page. I would like to know if it is possible to manage both donations and subscriptions in the same request.

Let me be more clear about the requirement.

When the user clicks a custom subscribe button, a page with a text field to enter a donation amount will be displayed. Suppose, the user enters a random amount. The user will then click the PayPal subscribe button and will be taken to the PayPal site for the payment. Both the subscription and donation have to be managed separately so that I can easily identify which one is subscription fee and which one is donated amount by looking into the PayPal statements.

Please let me know if this is possible with website payments standard. If not, can you please help me how to achieve this?

My additional requirements are:

1. I need to combine Add to cart button and Donations too.
2. I would like to manage subscriptions just like Add to cart feature. i.e., Paying for multiple subscriptions at once.

I am looking forward to your reply.

Answer (score 1):

Is not possible to make both "Donations" and "subscriptions"  in a single payment. Unless you treat the donation as an additional amount for your subscriptions initial payment.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Will it be possible if I use any other service other than Website Payments Standard?

Comment: I was checking the documentation and I believe is not possible. Also, I have never seen something like that.

About your additional requirements:
1. Same answer, you would need to treat the donation as an item of your cart.
2. You can always create a logical subscription which cover all items added to your cart, this is more part of your business logic.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response!